# Python List iteration over other list

Tags: python, list

I have these 2 lists:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst2 = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want this output:

```
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
4 - d
5 - a
6 - b
7 - c
8 - d
9 - a
10 - b
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Did you try anything? Maybe a search engine? `zip`

Comment: I tried but not getting the required answer

Answer (score 4):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip both lists together, and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat the second list:

```
from itertools import cycle

lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst2 = ['a','b','c','d']

for x, y in zip(lst1, cycle(lst2)):
    print(f"{x} - {y}")
```

Output:

```
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
4 - d
5 - a
6 - b
7 - c
8 - d
9 - a
10 - b
```

Answer (score 4):

This works easy if lst1 is always greater than lst2

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for i in range(len(lst1)):
    j = i % len(lst2)
    print(lst1[i],' - ',lst2[j])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the index number modulo the length of lst2 that will return the relevant index in lst1.

```
for line in ["{} - {}".format(v, lst2[i % len(lst2)]) for i, v in enumerate(lst1)]:
    print(line)
```

or

```
print(*["{} - {}".format(v, lst2[i % len(lst2)]) for i, v in enumerate(lst1)], sep="\n")
```

Output

```
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
4 - d
5 - a
6 - b
7 - c
8 - d
9 - a
10 - b
```